# The limit of $ f(x , y) = \frac{x^2 + \sin ^2 y}{2x^2 + y^2}$ along the y-axis. What is the meaning of 'the limit along the y-axis'?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

The limit of $ f(x , y) = \frac{x^2 + \sin ^2 y}{2x^2 + y^2}$ along the y-axis.  What is the meaning of 'the limit along the y-axis' ?

**My attempt :** I think we need to find the limit when $y \to \infty$ and $x$ remains a fixed number . For any fixed $ x = c$ , $ \lim_{y \to \infty } \frac{c^2 + \sin ^2 y}{2c^2 + y^2} = 0$.

So we can say the limit of $ f(x , y) = \frac{x^2 + \sin ^2 y}{2x^2 + y^2}$ along the y-axis is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

So, in single variable calculus, you talk about left handed and right handed limits. Basically, when you approach a point from different directions, you may get different results, like:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}$$

This goes to infinity from the right hand side and negative infinity from the left hand side. So no limit exists in the absolute sense, but we can talk about these times of side based limits.

For multivariable calculus, we take the limit to a coordinate (e.g. (3, 2)). The direction in $R^2$ that you approach this point can change the outcome though. You can do a lot of things like from an axis, along $y=x^2$, or more, and they may produce differing results. Note that a limit only exists if all limits from all directions approach the same value (something much harder to prove than in single variable). Your case just asks for the limit along the y-axis. When you add a bounds to the limit, you can reduce it to single variable effectively (as we will see below).

Now to actually solve your question, what you do for the limit along the y axis is to assume that we are on the y-axis and approach some value (let's say $(x_0, y_0)$).

On the y-axis,  $x=0$. So just set this to be true. Note this assumes that $(x_0, y_0)$ lies on the y-axis, so $x_0 = 0$

$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (x_0, y_0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{y -> y_0} f(0, y_0) = \lim_{y\rightarrow y_0}\frac{{\sin}^2y}{y^2}$$